# Decision tree outcomes

Tags: tree, machine-learning, decision-tree

For all the same conditions, could decision tree come out with a different class label?
As an example, a 30 year-old person with low income, **accepted and rejected for credit card application?

Comment: I think you might need to provide more detail.

Comment: What language are you working in? What criteria are you using?  What have you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

The label should be consistent in the prediction phase after you pre-build your decision tree and fix the parameters.